# Store data in call center

Tags: salesforce-id, php

I am using the salesforce developer account and I have tried to get contact information using the SOAP API WSDL. I have got the data using this code like:

```
require_once ('SforcePartnerClient.php');
$mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
$mySforceConnection->createConnection("partner.wsdl.xml");
$mySforceConnection->login(USERNAME, PASSWORD.SECURITY_TOKEN);
$query = "Select
Opportunity.Account.Id,

Opportunity.Account.Owner.Phone,
Opportunity.Account.Owner.Email,
Opportunity.Account.Phone

From OpportunityLineItem";

$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
```

Now I want to store the call details in call center using the API but I don't have any idea about table name and fields to store call details. So can you plese help me work out which table I need to use and what are the fileds in that?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The fields that are in the reports in the 'Call Center Reports' folder are based on task and events object.

Comment: So do you have any idea what is the table name from which they will get data?

Comment: If you're referring to object then you can go to setUp-> customize->activities -> event field / task fields.

Comment: But still can't get exact idea about table name and fields.So please can you help me.Specifically i wan to get the call related table in which i can store data.

Comment: You can find more info here http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_task.htm#topic-title and here http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_event.htm#topic-title. It will give you the object name and the field names.

Comment: still not get any idea.There are so many field are there so is it all in 1 table or it is all feilds of all tables?If it is all fileds of all tables then which fields are in call details related table?